# Is there a reference for an explicit computation of persistent homology?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

Does anyone know any source containing an example of persistent homology being explicitly, manually calculated? That is, as opposed to being calculated on by computer.

I am just looking for a simple example with a few simplices that can be worked out by hand for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Computational Topology an Introduction](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-69/) by Edelsbrunner and Harer they manually compute the reduced persistent homology of a $2$-simplex. They use reduced homology to give it some level of interest.